# my class gives no value back that I can use

Tags: c#, oop

this is how I try to print something worthwhile for my site using my class, When I try to write my class will not find it at all.

I can not find my worth to return something worthwhile for my user.

the problem is that it can not find at all class.

My class:

```
public class AbonnementsId
{
    public int indhold { get; set; }
}

public AbonnementsId HentAbonnementsId()
{
    AbonnementsId AbonnementsidReturn = new AbonnementsId();

    AbonnementsidReturn.indhold = 0;

    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;
    int brugerid = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]);
    cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT abonnementsid from brugere WHERE id = @id";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", brugerid);
    conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader readerBrugerA = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    if (readerBrugerA.Read())
    {
        AbonnementsidReturn.indhold = Convert.ToInt32(readerBrugerA["abonnementsid"]);
    }
    conn1.Close();
    return AbonnementsidReturn;
}
```

Here is how I write my class out when I need it for my content.

```
if (Session["AbonnementsId"] != null)
        {
            _subscriptionId = long.Parse(Session["AbonnementsId"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            //when I need to print my class do I like it here
            _subscriptionId = AbonnementsidReturn.indhold();
        }
```

Comment: What does _"it can not find at all class"_ mean exactly? What does happen?

Comment: I think you probably want to change that line to `_subscriptionId = AbonnementsId.HentAbonnementsId().indhold;` and make that a static method

Comment: @Prescott now its coming and say: "The name 'AbonnementsId' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You should follow current naming conventions. For example public properties should start with Capital letters. e.g. `public int IndHold { get; set; }` (PascalCasing) and private properties should be camel case. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm totally shooting in the dark here:

```
public static class AbonnementsId
{
    public static int GetAbonnementsId()
    {
        int abonnementsid;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            int brugerid = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]);

            SqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT abonnementsid from brugere WHERE id = @id";
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", brugerid);
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader readerBrugerA = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (readerBrugerA.Read())
                abonnementsid = Convert.ToInt32(readerBrugerA["abonnementsid"]);

            conn.Close();
        }

        return abonnementsid;
    }
}
```

You can then call this in your code:

```
if (Session["AbonnementsId"] != null)
{
    _subscriptionId = long.Parse(Session["AbonnementsId"].ToString());
}
else
{
    //when I need to print my class do I like it here
    _subscriptionId = AbonnementsId.GetAbonnementsId();
}
```

Comment: After re-reading this, I don't think you'd need a class for it - just create the method and return an integer..